# Update multible rows in mysql one by one

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update multible rows in one query

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
include("_models.header.php");
$model= $_GET["modelname"];
$timestamp= date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
mysql_query("UPDATE groupshows SET showended='".$timestamp."' WHERE model='".$model."' AND showended='0'");
mysql_query("UPDATE groupshows SET ended='1' WHERE model='".$model."' AND customer='0'");
mysql_query("UPDATE groupshows SET started='0' WHERE model='".$model."' AND customer='0'");


//udregn show cost
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groupshows where model ='".$model."' AND  customer='0'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
$id=$row["groupshowid"];

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groupshows where groupshowid='".$id."' and cost='0' limit 1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $customer=$row["customer"];
    $cost=$row["cost"];
    $startime=$row["showstarted"];
    $endtime=$row["showended"];
}
if ($cost=='0'){

    $to_time = strtotime($endtime);
//echo "endtime $to_time<br>";
$from_time = strtotime($starttime);
//echo "start $from_time<br>";
$timespend=round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);
$timespend2=date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$timespend);
//echo "timespend $timespend<br>";
$cost=number_format($timespend,0)*0.39;
$cost2=$cost/100;
//echo "cost $cost<br>";
//echo "Show started $starttime Show ended $timestamp<br>";
$Earn=number_format($cost, 2)/100;
//echo "<b>total cost $ $cost2</b>";

mysql_query("UPDATE groupshows SET cost=cost + '".$cost."' Where customer='".$customer."' AND cost='0'");
$result++;
}
```

I can't get to take the time stamps in the starttime and endtime for the different customers, it will update the first row but will not go to the next and then I think it take the models start and endtime not the customers

In Database:
id      groupshowid      model    customerid  customer signs   started  userstarte
17  BMli3Ggb    ilovecock    0           0   3    0          0
  Show started               showended         cost    users   ended
2013-11-29 04:25:04     2013-11-29 04:29:37     1   0   1

18  BMli3Ggb    ilovecock   0   tomdodi     0   0   1

2013-11-29 04:25:04     2013-11-29 05:01:24     8.97    0   0

19  BMli3Ggb    ilovecock   0   test    0   0   0   2013-11-29 04:25:04     2013-11-29 04:26:37     0   0   0

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE groupshows SET showended='".$timestamp."' WHERE model='".$model."' AND showended='0'"); After AND, Should showended be customer??

Comment: Show ended is different from customer to customer, a customer desides him self to leave this is a pick up if the model leaves while still customers

Comment: Only in db is same is the groupshow id and show started = 1 attribute

Comment: What if you had manygroup shows where showended was 0, it would update all?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to move a few items around, namely the `if ($cost =='0') {` block into the second `while` loop. Otherwise, you'll only be updating the last record found. Additionally, I think the following may be closer to what you intended:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
include("_models.header.php");
$model= $_GET["modelname"];
$timestamp= date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
mysql_query("UPDATE groupshows SET showended='".$timestamp."' WHERE model='".$model."' AND showended='0'");
mysql_query("UPDATE groupshows SET ended='1', started='0' WHERE model='".$model."' AND customer='0'");

//udregn show cost
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groupshows where model ='".$model."' AND  customer='0'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $id=$row["groupshowid"];

  $result2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM groupshows where groupshowid='".$id."' and cost='0' limit 1");
  while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {
    $customer=$row2["customer"];
    $cost=$row2["cost"];
    $startime=$row2["showstarted"];
    $endtime=$row2["showended"];

    if ($cost=='0') {

      $to_time = strtotime($endtime);
      //echo "endtime $to_time<br>";
      $from_time = strtotime($starttime);
      //echo "start $from_time<br>";
      $timespend=round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);
      $timespend2=date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$timespend);
      //echo "timespend $timespend<br>";
      $cost=number_format($timespend,0)*0.39;
      $cost2=$cost/100;
      //echo "cost $cost<br>";
      //echo "Show started $starttime Show ended $timestamp<br>";
      $Earn=number_format($cost, 2)/100;
      //echo "<b>total cost $ $cost2</b>";

      mysql_query("UPDATE groupshows SET cost=cost + '".$cost."' Where customer='".$customer."' AND cost='0'");
    }
    // result is a mysql result resource (and can't be incremented like this)
    // $result++;
  }
}
```

Unrelated to the question but the second and third UPDATE statements could be combined into one query: `UPDATE groupshows SET ended='1', started='0' WHERE model='".$model."' AND customer='0'");`

Here's a [gist of your original code vs. this change](https://gist.github.com/nbrew/7713188).

Comment: in the database I have the model in a row for her self, then i have 2 customers in the show  with following.  groupshowid= BMli3Ggb model=ilovecock customer=tomdodi userstarted= 1  showstarted=2013-11-29 04:25:04 showended=2013-11-29 05:01:24

Comment: groupshowid= BMli3Ggb model=ilovecock customer=test userstarted=1  showstarted=2013-11-29 04:25:04 show ended=2013-11-29 04:26:37

Comment: Both the showstarted and show ended can be different because they can jump in and out the show